# Uniqueness of canonical conjunctive normal form

Tags: logic

Could someone explain me why is there for each formula one and only one equivalent canonical conjunctive normal form? Like, I understood how to derive one by using the truth tables but I'm still asking myself how to prove this statement in a formal way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about it this way: two statements are equivalent if and only if they have the same truth table, and there is exactly one canonical conjunctive form for every truth-table.

It follows that there is exactly one canonical conjunctive form that is equivalent to a given statement.

The key then, if you want to prove it formally, is to do the following two things:

- for an arbitrary truth-table, find a canonical conjunctive normal form with that truth table
- given that two canonical conjunctive normal forms have the same truth table, show that the expressions must be identical.

Comment: thanks, it makes a lot of sense!

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, can I convert two boolean expressions into their canonical SOP/POS form to prove their equivalence? If canonical form is unique they should match, right?

Comment: @Samik correct.${}{}{}$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom - Do you have a reference for the uniqueness? It seems to me [this post](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/55182/21921) contradicts the uniqueness. What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see how the first is in CNF

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I haven't been alerted and saw it by chance. (It might be more prudent to use the @ sign.) If I understand correctly, you're saying that you don't see how $A\land B$ is in CNF. This is the fourth example in [this Wikipedia subentry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form#Examples_and_non-examples).

Comment: You can also look at [this WolframAlpha link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=A+and+B&rawformassumption=%7B%22C%22,+%22A%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Variable%22%7D&rawformassumption=%7B%22C%22,+%22and%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22MathOperator%22%7D).

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard my apologies for leaving it out the @. In any case, it seems that (according to your links) I misunderstood the definition of CNF back when I answered this; my understanding was that the CNF was necessarily was expanded to include all "maxterms".  That is, I would have said that $A \wedge B$ is in *a conjunctive form* but not in *the canonical conjunctive form* as neither $A$ nor $B$ are maxterms.  That is, was thinking of CCNF, i.e. [canonical conjunctive form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form).

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard in fact, looking at the question, he is indeed asking specifically about the *canonical* CNF, so I was accidentally right.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard It is well known that CNFs are not unique.  In fact, the problem of finding a *minimal* CNF (i.e. with the fewest terms) is important in electrical engineering and can be solved using [Karnaugh diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).

Comment: I also missed the "canonical". Sorry! Now everything is clear. Thanks!